# With negative $b,$ is there any sense that $a$ is $x$ times greater than $b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R^+$ and $b\le a$. By taking $b$ as reference, I have no doubt about using the computation $x = \dfrac{a}{b}$ to calculate how many times $a$ is greater. But when $a,b \in \mathbb R, $ does the $x$ value make sense with

1. $a$ and $b$ both negative;
2. $a$ positive and $b$ negative ?

Examples:

- $ x = \frac{10}{2} = 5$, is 5 five times greater, this is OK
- $ x = \frac{10}{-2} = -5$, this is not necessarily $|-5|$ times greater because the difference is $ 10-(-2) = 12$, only if I take absolute values for that
- $ x = \frac{-5}{-8}=0.6$, I'm not sure if this has any meaning.

What about when working  with temperatures and wanting to know how many times greater is a temperature is than a reference temperature, for instance: reference $-15^{\circ}$ and the other temperature $-4^{\circ}$ ? In this case do I apply reciprocal and use $x = \frac{b}{a}$ instead?

I read these related questions before posting this question: 
["$x$ times as many as" versus "$x$ times more than"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517954/how-many-times-vs-how-many-times-greater) 
[Finding number $n$ times larger then a given negative number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697705/finding-number-n-times-larger-then-a-given-negative-numberr) 
[How many times larger is 5 × 106 than 5 × 102?"How much is it more/small than" calculator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1059925).

Comment: I agree with the answer of 311411 and would add two points: [1] Normally, given **dimensionless** real numbers $a,b$, in my **limited** experience, the question of how many times *greater* $a$ is than $b$ refers to a comparison of $|a|$ and $|b|$. [2] As 311411's examples suggest, comparison of **dimensioned** numbers $a$, $b$ requires that $0$ be delineated.  So, when comparing two temperatures, using Kelvin gives a different answer than using Celsius.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/697726/139123) to a question you linked to suggests that you look at the absolute values of both numbers so that you take the ratio of two positive numbers.

Comment: When you mention the temperature $-4^\circ$, it makes me suspect that you are asking the wrong question entirely. $2^\circ$ Celsius is not twice as hot as $1^\circ$ Celsius. There are scientific and engineering applications for a ratio of temperatures, but it is always a ratio of *absolute* temperatures, so you cannot take ratios of Celsius measurements directly.

Comment: @DavidK  yes, but in that answer he defined the operation in that way for convenience, maybe he is  considering what  user2661023 answered. And  the temperature example was only for proposes of introduce the theme in something more related user2661923 introduce: the dimensioned numbers  and the importance  that $0$ must be delineated.

Comment: Don't blame the temperature example on user2661923. You wrote that into the question before anyone had commented or answered. As for "convenience," virtually every definition in mathematics could be said to be "for convenience," because it is convenient to have definitions that make sense and that you can more easily do mathematics with than definitions that are difficult or impossible to work with.

Comment: "greater" is a troublesome word.  It could mean "bigger" or it could mean "take the notable attribute of that number, it's of size $5$ in the negaitve direction... now make it $7$ times more extreme in that attribute... so it is size $35$ in the negative direction".  In math we really mean the latter.  But "greater" is just a word.  DOn't get hung up on it.  Words are only words.

Comment: Temperature is a weird example also as the "origin" point of $0$ is completely arbitrary.  To say, in San Francisco, that $80^\circ F$ is twice as warm as $40^\circ F$ is ... just meaningless.  $40^\circ$ isn't warm at all.  It's cold.

Comment: In germany , quantities are also often wrongly used : If we say : "fünfmal höher als der Eiffelturm" (five times higher than the tour Eiffel) , it should be $6$ times the height of the Eiffelturm , but usually actually $5$ times is meant. No idea why.

Comment: For a negative number , such a formulation does not make any sense. We should instead describe the absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

I find your example of temperature interesting. There is a unit of temperature called Kelvin that avoids negative values entirely. Kelvin temperature is also called "absolute temperature". It seems ***absolute temperature*** is proportional to energy, and it seems reasonable to say things like "three times the energy".

Conversely, there is nothing wrong with saying "LeBron James is three times the height of my cousin." But I could introduce a ridiculous new unit of length in which Lebron is -102 units while my cousin is -168.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no doubt about using the computation $x = \dfrac{a}{b}$ to calculate how many times $a$ is greater.

> $ x = \frac{10}{-2} = -5$, this is not necessarily $|-5|$ times greater because the difference is $ 10-(-2) = 12$

Aren't you contradicting yourself: you claim to have no doubt that $39$ is three times greater than $13,$ then subsequently suggest that their difference $26$ ought to be considered so that $39$ should be considered two times greater than $13.$

The fact is, given any real $A$ and any nonzero real $B,$ the statement

- “$a$ is $x$ times bigger than $b$”

has [various readings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4722720/21813):

- $$x=\frac{A-B}{|B|}$$ Technically correct reading; here "bigger" and "more" are treated as synonyms.
- $$x=\frac{|A|-|B|}{|B|}$$ Another technically correct reading; here "bigger" refers to magnitude.
- $$x=\frac{|A|}{|B|}$$ Popular but technically problematic reading (it suggests that $13$ is one time bigger than $13$); here "bigger" refers to magnitude.

> What about when working  with temperatures and wanting to know how many times greater is a temperature is than a reference temperature

Observe that $$x\text{°C} \ne (x+273)\text{K}.$$ (Otherwise, we would have that $$0\text{°C} = 273\text{K}\\2\times0\text{°C} = 2\times273\text{K} \\0\text{°C} = 546\text{K}.)$$ The inequation's left and right sides have different zero points and merely *correspond* to each other, so it is not meaningful to quantitatively compare them.