# How many times larger is 5 × 106 than 5 × 102?"How much is it more/small than" calculator.

Tags: calculator

I need to find a calculator that will essentially give me how ever much a number is smaller/bigger than another number.

Example:
If I enter the two numbers '1' and '4'.

It will tell me, `'4' is x4 times larger than '1'`

This should also work with floatation point numbers, in the case that there is not such a calculator, the number that I need to calculate is `0.6` and `1.0`.

Thank you very much, and sorry for the lack of research, but I really do not know how to word this correctly, I hope anyone reading understands.

Comment: Have you tried, ehm, dividing the numbers?

Comment: @ajotatxe I am so sorry for being so stupid, I have no idea how I literally managed to not realize that.. Thank you so much

Comment: 4 is [three times larger](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4722720/21813) than 1; 4 is zero times larger than 4; 4 is one time larger than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the largest one by the smallest one : for example, the number $4$ is $\frac{4}{2}=2\times$ larger than the number $2$.

Indeed, If you multiply $2$ by $\frac{4}{2}$ you'll get 4.

Of course, if a number is $n\times$ larger than another, then this other is $n\times$ smaller than the first one.

It will of course work with floating point :
$0.6\times\frac{1}{0.6}≈0.6\times 1.6667 = 1$ so $1$ is $\text{~}1.6667$ times larger than $0.6$ while $0.6$ is $\text{~}1.6667$ smaller than $1$.

Answer (score 8):

The term you are looking for is **division**, which (thankfully) is already on most calculators.

Comment: Your answer reminded me of [this one](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/14596).